Python sys.path confusion between multiple repo copies
I have multiple copies of the same repository like so:
.
├── my_repo
├── my_repo2
├── my_repo3
└── my_repo4

I am running a Python script inside repo4 with the following code:
from local_module import (
    fnc1,
    fnc2,
    fnc3
)

The local_module appears in all four repos. However, Python does not seem to import the local_module from repo4 - it imports from repo2. I have previously run the script in repo2. When I print out sys.path I looks like this:
['/mnt/c/repo4/pathtomyscript, '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/mnt/c/repo4/.venv-lin/lib/python3.8/site-packages', '/mnt/c/repo2/pathtomodule1', '/mnt/c/repo2/pathtomodule2', '/mnt/c/repo2/pathtomodule3', ...]

Notably sys.path contains paths to modules inside repo2. What is going on here? Are these paths cached by Python? How can I remove them?
I do not want any hacky solution, e.g., sys.path.clear().
